# how to execute section of php depending on which button is submitted

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have several sections of code that insert values into different tables in my DB.

I am wondering if there is a way to capture which button on my form has been selected so when the page reloads it only executes the one insert statement?

this is how I submit to the same page

```
<form name="input" action=myawesomeform.php" method="POST">
```

This is what my submit button looks like

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="5050gdmyButton" />
```

so pretty much I want to execute one of the insert statements depending on which button was selected..

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The `input`s require a `name` attribute value, which is the key used on the server to get the corresponding value in that `input` element. `id` does not count.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) You need to give **name attribute** to your submit button

2) when you have multiple inputs in your form and when you press one of them, then you only get that one in your php code with name attribute.

So for example:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit1" value="add" id="5050gdmyButton1" />
<input type="submit" name="submit2" value="update" id="5050gdmyButton2" />
```

in your php

```
if(isset($_POST['submit1']) && $_POST['submit1'] == 'add'){
// do insert for first one
}

if(isset($_POST['submit2']) && $_POST['submit2']== 'update'){
// do update for second one
}
```

Comment: bam! finally got it working with your help.. thanks very much.. I kept mixing up the isset values

Comment: @vascowhite thanks to bring it in my attention. i know id must unique but it's my mistake in my answer.i edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

you can give two different names for submit button like this..

```
 <input type="submit" name="button1" value="Button1" id="5050gdmyButton" />
 <input type="submit" name="button2" value="Button2" id="5051gdmyButton" />
```

In the Receiving page use the condition like this...

```
 if ($_POST['button1'])
  {
  //do your first button process
  }
  elseif($_POST['button2'])
 {
  //do you second button process
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are having more than one submit button than you should make a different name for each button

```
 <input type="submit" value="addSubmitButton" id="5050gdmyButton1" />
//to add value in db
<input type="submit" value="removeSubmitButton" id="5050gdmyButton2" />
//to remove value in db
```

in your serverside

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["addSubmitButton"])){
//add value in db
}


if(isset($_POST["removeSubmitButton"])){
//remove data from database
}



?>
```

Comment: @vascowhite we are not using javascript.I am just showing how to use.GOT IT

Comment: It doesn't matter, ID's must be unique, somebody else may use your answer and get unexpected results and not understand why. You only need to edit 1 letter to make this right.

Comment: Now, that wasn't so hard was it?

Comment: @vascowhite I know that.But i was just showing how to do this

Comment: So show it right, you are, in effect, teaching people here. Get it as right as possible.

Answer (score 0):

just but a name tag inside input

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="5050gdmyButton" name="5050gdmyButton" />
```

and in php check if name isset()

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['5050gdmyButton'])){ //do somthing }
```